# C#からExcel印刷するとサーバー使用中ダイアログが表示されるのを回避する方法

Tags: c#, windows, excel, com

プリンタにXPSを指定した状態で、C#からWorksheet.PrintOutを実行すると、ファイル保存ダイアログが表示されますが。
その状態で少し放置すると、サーバー使用中ダイアログがでてきてしまいます。
サーバー使用中ダイアログを表示させない方法は、印刷を別スレッドで実行するしかないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

タイマーを使用して、別スレッドで実行することで解決しました。